# How can I string format a decimal (multiple of 0.5) as a whole or mixed number?

Tags: c#, string, decimal, string-formatting, fractions

How can I string format a decimal (always a multiple of 0.5) as a whole or mixed number.

examples:

```
0.00 .... "" or "0"  
0.50 .... "1/2"  
1.00 .... "1"  
1.50 .... "1 1/2"
```

and so on..

EDIT:
This might be what I was looking for. But I haven't tried it yet. I imagine there is a Regex for this kind of thing.

```
public static string ToMixedNumber(this decimal d)
{
    if (d == null || d == 0) return "";
    var s = d.ToString().TrimEnd('0');
    if(s.EndsWith(".")) return s.TrimEnd('.');
    return s.TrimEnd('.') + " 1/2";
}
```

Comment: You'll have to write: `string NumberAsFraction(decimal d)`

Comment: Wy would you want to do that?

Comment: This is tough because you're forcing us down a very narrow assumption of always being a .50 multiple, I have code that does what you want, but it makes me feel all dirty inside...

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare - No little wonder for this, eh...

Comment: Programmers always talk about feeling dirty inside. It is kinda creepy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using,

```
public static string ToMixedNumber(this decimal d)
{
    if (d == 0) return "";
    var s = d.ToString().TrimEnd('0');
    if (s.EndsWith(".")) return s.TrimEnd('.');
    return s.Split('.')[0] + " 1/2";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't using the default formatters. You would have to implement an [ICustomFormatter Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.aspx) and write your own code to create appropriate fractions from the decimal part.

Comment: I implemented an IMustHaveAskedTheQuestionWrong interface instead but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Heres an implementation as suggested by JamieSee:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class FractionFormatter :ICustomFormatter, IFormatProvider
{
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        // Provide default formatting for unsupported argument types.
        if (!(arg is decimal))
        {
            HandleOtherFormats(format, arg);
        }

        // Provide default formatting for unsupported format strings.
        string ufmt = format.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (ufmt != "H")
        {
            try
            {
                return HandleOtherFormats(format, arg);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                throw new FormatException(String.Format("The format of '{0}' is invalid.", format), e);
            }
        }

        decimal value = (decimal)arg;
        int wholeNumber = (int)Math.Floor(value);
        decimal fraction = value - (decimal)wholeNumber;

        if (fraction == 0m)
        {
            return wholeNumber.ToString();
        }
        else if (fraction == 0.5m)
        {
            if (wholeNumber == 0)
            {
                return "1/2";
            }
            else
            {
                return wholeNumber.ToString() + " 1/2";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("arg", "Value must be a multiple of 0.5");
        }

    }

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;
        else
            return null;
    }

    private string HandleOtherFormats(string format, object arg)
    {
        if (arg is IFormattable)
            return ((IFormattable)arg).ToString(format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        else if (arg != null)
            return arg.ToString();
        else
            return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

And here's an example of it in use:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(new FractionFormatter(), "{0:H}", value));
```

Comment: whoa, that is way fancy for me! But thank you very much for a presumably usable answer.